# Is there any way to renumber my Access table field with c#, after a record is deleted in the middle?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a POS app for restaurants. In my app, each food category has its own ID number which I use for many purposes in my app. I want all my category IDs to renumber from 1 when I delete one category.

For example:
I have 5 food categories, their IDs are from 1 to 5. When I delete number 3, I want all the IDs to renumber like this: 1,2,3,4, and I dont want to have any numbers missing in the middle, like: 1,2,4,5 which would affect another part of my app. 
For more info (the ID field in Access table is not an autonumber, but a number, and I use **c#** instead to increase numbers whenever a new category is added using the app itself).

I tried many ways to renumber the ID field , like update statement.
 Here is the code that I used ( after a record is deleted).

```
string CmdTxt = "SELECT COUNT(CategoryId) FROM Categories";
OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(CmdTxt, Connection);
Connection.Open();
int count = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar());
Connection.Close();

 int row = 1;   // to specify the row I want to make changes in. 
 int newId = 1;    // to set new Id for each specified row. 

for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
{

   // from here the problem starts...

   string CmdTxt1 = "UPDATE Categories ROW"+row+" 
                    SET[CategoryId]=@ParaNewId";


   OleDbCommand Command1 = new OleDbCommand(CmdTxt1, Connection);

   Command1.Parameters.Add("@ParaNewId", newId); 
   // have no problems with parameters. 

   Connection.Open();
   Command11.ExecuteNonQuery();
   Connection.Close();
   row++; 
   newId++; 

}
```

I tried this code. It gave me syntax error. And, I know that there is a mistake with the CmdTxt1.

Here I want to ask another question: is there another way to specify or select the row number I want to make changes in? 
Because if I run this code without specifying the row, all `CategoryId` column cells will have the same number every time the for-loop repeats.

Comment: Do you have other tables with records that link to specific Category IDs?  If so, and you change the IDs, then some/many of those records will no longer be pointing at the correct Category.  Your SQL statement looks a bit garbled, but at a minimum you need to cast the row to a string before concatenating.  `+ row.ToString() +`

Comment: `UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeField = @SomeValue WHERE SomeField = @SomeId`

Comment: You should rethink this.  ID numbers should be keys the database uses, not end users.

Comment: The Answer to your question is Yes,  but I thought about that. I can handle it if I could renumber my Category IDs. And yeah I know my SQL statement is not right. I already used the code you have just commented and it gave me duplicate values.

Comment: Re-sequencing an Id is a singularly bad idea.  First, the Id is not supposed to have any intrinsic meaning or  role beyond being a unique identifier.  Second, it is not your `Id`, the DB should be issuing it.  Third, it is a *relational* DB so there ought be things relying on that value not to change.  Just say *No*.  Fourth, your app is leaking - things which implement `IDisposable` ought to be disposed.

Comment: *I dont want to have any numbers missing in the middle* **WHY??**  If you need a *display value* don't use the key.

Comment: (Pro tip: we don't use [solved] title devices here. Instead, find an answer you most prefer, and click the tick/check button. If there is no answer that matches your solution, write your own and accept that).

Comment: I am a 1-day old User, thanks for the tip, halfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the ire you've attracted on the comments, you shouldn't do this. Primary key ID numbers uniquely identify a single row in the database table and should not be changed. Mostly they also shouldn't be shown to the end user because you're likely to want some greater degree of control over appearance, and also that showing the user your ids might lead they to try guessing other IDs if they're able to (for example changing the account number shown in a URL to see if they can break into someone else's account). Strive to keep your IDs internal use only and let the database manage them for what it needs.

So let's say you're developing this system and you want the user to be able to press 1 thru 5 as a shortcut key to get into a category, but you want to make sure that the numbers are contiguous. Specify your table like:

```
CategoryID int primary key autonumber
ShortcutKey int not null
CategoryName varchar(or text, or whatever access calls it) not null
```

When the time comes to delete a category the operations you require are:

```
conn.Open();
var cmd  = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM categories WHERE shortcutkey = ?", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", 3); // remove key 3 - you'll make this variable chosen by the user of course
cmd  = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE categories SET shortcutkey = shortcutkey - 1 WHERE shortcutkey > ?", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", 3); // again, make variable
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

You're leaving your ID alone, you're updating the thing the users see. It's easier to get the database to delete 3 and shuffle down everything above 3 than it is to count things and loop and adjust etc.

Consider that leaving the ID alone can actually help answer other questions. Suppose a user comes to you and says "the shortcut key categories are different today, why?" And you look at the ID values and they're `1,2,4,5,6` whereas most users never change their keys so you're used to seeing `1,2,3,4,5`.. you can say "it looks like someone deleted the third one and added another recently". Or if you see id numbers of `34,78,99,120,356` you can think "wow, these guys change their shortcut keys a lot, let's get in touch and see if it's a pain point of something we can improve- users always want explanations and without one they blame the computer system for their own errors, which can make the commercial aspect of supporting a system very hard work

Comment: Good point. So you are telling to leave the ID alone and create another int field in my table with 'shortcut key' name or whatever, and use that instead of ID. Well, I have done that, and your code is working well. that's what I was actually looking for. Thank you so much!